# Android spinner loads contents based on multiple table data column comparison

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I have an UI that consists of a three spinner and a table.  (Spinner1, Spinner2, Spinner3) respectively. Spinner2,Spinner3 swap value based on selection of Spinner1. inserting the conents in to the table(LABELS2) as per my requirments

Spinner1,Spinner2,Spinner3 value is retrieved from one table `"LABELS"`.

All three spinner value is inserted in to another table `"LABELS2"` while clicking the save button.

Requirement: Spinner2 should load contents based on comparision between table "Labels" and "Labels2".

Idea behind is to avoid duplication in the data insert and to know how many records is left after saving the data.

Example: Table "Labels" is having three record

```
1.("A1”,”EXTRA1”,”MORE1");
2,("A1”,”EXTRA2”,”MORE2");
3,("A1”,”EXTRA2”,”MORE2");
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHandler mDH;
    Spinner mSpinner1,mSpinner2,mSpinner3;
    Cursor mSpinner1Csr,mSpinner2Csr,mSpinner3Csr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSpinner1Adapter,mSpinner2Adapter,mSpinner3Adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSpinner1 = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        mSpinner2 = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        mSpinner3 = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        mDH = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        addSomeTestingData(); // ADD testing data if none
        manageSpinner1(); // Manages spinner1 not that spinner 1 invokes manage spinner2 and spinnr manages spinner3

    }

    private void addSomeTestingData() {
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDH.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LABELS) > 0) return;

        // Data for LABELS2 table (spinner 1 (note 1st column listed in spinner))
        mDH.insertLabel("A1”,”EXTRA1”,”MORE1");
        mDH.insertLabel("A1”,”EXTRA2”,”MORE2");
        mDH.insertLabel("A1”,”EXTRA3”,”MORE5");

        mDH.insertLabel1("A1EXTRA1");
        mDH.insertLabel1("A1EXTRA2");
        mDH.insertLabel1("B1EXTRA1");
        mDH.insertLabel1("B1EXTRA2");
        mDH.insertLabel1("L1EXTRA1");
        mDH.insertLabel1("L1EXTRA2");

        // Data for LABELS table (spinner 1,2,3)
        mDH.insertlabel("A1”,”EXTRA1”,”MORE1");
        mDH.insertlabel("A1”,”EXTRA2”,”MORE2");
        mDH.insertlabel("A1”,”EXTRA3”,”MORE5");

    }

    private void manageSpinner1() {
        mSpinner1Csr = mDH.getAllLabelsForSpinner1AsCursor();
        if (mSpinner1Adapter == null) {
            mSpinner1Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mSpinner1Csr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mSpinner1.setAdapter(mSpinner1Adapter);
            mSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    manageSpinner2(mSpinner1Csr.getString(mSpinner1Csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.ROUTE)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSpinner1Adapter.swapCursor(mSpinner1Csr);
        }
    }
    private void manageSpinner2(String keyFromSpinner1) {
        mSpinner2Csr = mDH.getAllLabelsForSpinner2AsCursor(keyFromSpinner1);
        if (mSpinner2Adapter == null) {
            mSpinner2Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mSpinner2Csr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHandler.ROUTE},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mSpinner2.setAdapter(mSpinner2Adapter);
            mSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    manageSpinner3(mSpinner2Csr.getString(mSpinner2Csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.ROUTE)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            mSpinner2Adapter.swapCursor(mSpinner2Csr);
        }
    }

    private void manageSpinner3(String keyForSpinner3) {
        mSpinner3Csr = mDH.getAllLabelsForSpinner3AsCursor(keyForSpinner3);
        if (mSpinner3Adapter == null) {
            mSpinner3Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mSpinner3Csr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_ID},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mSpinner3.setAdapter(mSpinner3Adapter);
        } else {
            mSpinner3Adapter.swapCursor(mSpinner3Csr);
        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHandler**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinnerExample";
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    // Database Name
    // Labels table name
    public static final String TABLE_LABELS = "labels"; //<<<< Made public
    public static final String TABLE_LABELS1= "labels1";
    public static final String TABLE_LABELS2= "labels2";
    // Labels Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID4 = "input_label";
    public static final String KEY_ID12 = "id2";           //<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_99 = "sno";           //<<<< Made public//<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";       //<<<< made public
    public static final String KEY_ID1 = "id1";           //<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_NAME1 = "name1";
    public static final String KEY_1 = "number";           //<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_2 = "outletname";       //<<<< made public
    public static final String KEY_3 = "sunday";           //<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_4 = "monday";
    public static final String KEY_5 = "tuesday";
    public static final String KEY_6 = "wednesday";
    public static final String KEY_7 = "thursday";
    public static final String KEY_8 = "saturday";
    public static final String KEY_9 = "closed";
    public static final String KEY_10 = "calling";
    public static final String KEY_11 = "id3";
    public static final String ROUTE= "route";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        // Category table create query
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("+ KEY_99 + " INTEGER,"
                + ROUTE + " TEXT," + KEY_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT)";
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS1 + "("
                + KEY_ID1+ " TEXT," + KEY_NAME1+ " TEXT)";
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS2 + "("
                + KEY_11+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_1+ " TEXT," + KEY_2+ " TEXT," + KEY_3+ " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE1);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE2);
    }
    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS1);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS2);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Inserting new lable into lables table
     * */



public void insertlabel(String text,String id9,String id, String label) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_99,text);
    cv.put(ROUTE,id9);
    cv.put(KEY_ID,id);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME,label);
    db.insert(TABLE_LABELS,null,cv);
    db.close();
}


    public void insertLabel(String message1, String message2,String message3){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_1, message1);
        values.put(KEY_2, message2);
        values.put(KEY_3,message3);
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LABELS2, null, values);
        //db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public void insertLabel1(String label){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME1, label);
        db.insert(TABLE_LABELS1, null, values);
        //db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public void insertLabel2(String label){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, label);
        db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    public Cursor getAllLabelsForSpinner1AsCursor() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"}; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_LABELS,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }


    public Cursor getAllLabelsForSpinner2AsCursor(String keyFromSinner1) {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"}; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TABLE_LABELS,columns,
                DatabaseHandler.ROUTE + " LIKE ?",
                new String[]{keyFromSinner1+"%"},
                null,null,null
        );
    }

    public Cursor getAllLabelsForSpinner3AsCursor(String keyFromSpinner2) {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"}; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TABLE_LABELS,columns,
                DatabaseHandler.ROUTE + " LIKE ?",
                new String[]{keyFromSpinner2 + "%"},
                null,null,null);
    }
}
```

Simulation:
As you can below selection of the first spinner "P1" shows his relevant information

[image]

now second spinner display the information based on first spinner selection.
[image]

we save the information on each selection.

Requirement is spinner 2 information should reduce upon data saving information.

example : if you select "9001234" then save information with "9001234" and next automatically should come "9003562" and so on as per saving the information.

Looking forward to any help.

Comment: add your spinner adapters code too for better understanding of what you have done till now.

Comment: @HaiderSaleem spinner adapter details already available..

Comment: Experts welcome your ideas

Comment: @tynn apologies for your confusion. Yes i have given information as per my requirements. I can rephrase it again if yo want. Of course many thanks indeed spend time on my question..

Comment: @mikeT can you spot the answer with your expertise?

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
public Cursor getRoutes(long name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String whereclause = KEY_NAME + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(name)};
    String sql = "SELECT customer_name,labels5.number,labels.id,customer._id,labels.route FROM customer left join labels ON customer._id = labels._id  LEFT JOIN labels5 ON labels5.number =  labels.route WHERE number IS NULL";
    return db.query(sql,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,ROUTE);
}
```

Comment: Even if it might work, those aliases are confusing - and code-snippets are useless for SQL.

Comment: @Leace the issue with the above example in the OP is, that the entries are not being loaded from a database, therefore it is quite difficult, if not impossible, to create cascaded drop-downs... there simply is nothing to run the SQL against.

Comment: @Mecido getting following error. android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM SELECT customer_name,labels5.number,labels.id,customer._id,labels.route FROM customer left join labels ON customer._id = labels._id  LEFT JOIN labels5 ON labels5.number =  labels.route WHERE number IS NULL WHERE _id=? ORDER BY route

Answer (score 0):

Second way

```
public Cursor getRoutes(long name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String whereclause = KEY_NAME + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(name)};
    String[] tableColumns = new String[]{"customer_name, labels5.number,labels.id,customer._id,labels.route FROM customer left join labels ON customer._id = labels._id  LEFT JOIN labels5 ON labels5.number =  labels.route where number is NULL "};
    //String orderBy = "ROUTE";
  // String tableColumns = SELECT customer_name, labels5.number,labels.id,customer._id,labels.route FROM customer left join labels ON customer._id = labels._id  LEFT JOIN labels5 ON labels5.number =  labels.route where number is NULL"  ;
    return db.query(TABLE_LABELS,tableColumns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,ROUTE);
}
```

Comment: error :  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT customer_name, labels5.number,labels.id,customer._id,labels.route FROM customer left join labels ON customer._id = labels._id  LEFT JOIN labels5 ON labels5.number =  labels.route where number is NULL  FROM labels WHERE _id=? ORDER BY route
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)